# what OS to use when it comes to iTunes usage on virtual machines?

Tags: performance, operating-systems, itunes

I'm interested in building a machine to VM iTunes to data wipe iPhones as part of recycling process.

Now I was wondering which OS (mac/windows) would have iTunes run as it best performance wise?
Also what other bottleneck should i work around(CPU? HDD R/W?).

any other tips would be much appreciated as I have never done this before.

Comment: iTunes only supports Windows and OS X.  Unless you have an Apple computer using OS X within virtual machine is difficult and against the terms of service.  It would be much easier just to use iTunes within a Windows virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is definitely easier to virtualize. You shouldn't have any performance problems with iTunes specifically on any OS.